# How to stop Chrome DevTools Sources tab from opening framework files on page reload

Tags: angular, google-chrome, intellij-idea, google-chrome-devtools

How do you stop Google Chrome DevTools Sources tab from opening framework files on page reload?  I am debugging an Angular project via IntelliJ and every time I reload a page, DevTools opens and pauses on about 5 to 10 different framework files for just under a second each, leaving a few open and closing others automatically.  I have even added them to the "Ignore list" (previously "Blackbox"), as well as setting the "Never pause here" breakpoint on the lines that are pausing, but nothing is working.

[image]

Comment: Are there breakpoints in these files? I think the idea of the blacklist is to stop you stepping into the files or exceptions being thrown from them rather than to ignore breakpoints in them.

Comment: There are no breakpoints anywhere